# Can't run library on machines that have anaconda installed

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm TA in a Programming course. This week's challenge was to build a basic chess game. Teacher made a `game.py` library, that would help them. The problem is, when calling the `LostGame` class, which is defined as follows (and uses `Arcade` library):

```
class LostGame(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
        self.sprites_list = None
        self.background = None
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.RED)
        self.moves = []
        self.doing = 0
        self.started = 0
        self.current_text = "Comienza el juego"
```

We will have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    juego = game.LostGame()
  File "/Users/daniel/Documents/Doctorado/Ayudantías/IIC2115/L02/game.py", line 39, in __init__
    super().__init__(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arcade/application.py", line 53, in __init__
    resizable=resizable, config=config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 643, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arcade/monkey_patch_pyglet.py", line 81, in _create
    self.context.attach(self.canvas)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/gl/cocoa.py", line 289, in attach
    self._nscontext.setView_(canvas.nsview)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setView_'
```

We noticed that this error would happen in all computers that have Anaconda installed. We thing it may be because it Anaconda's python doesn't recognise `Arcade` library. We have already ran the code on an independent version of `Python 3.7,` without success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: well it definitely recognizes that `arcade` is installed, you can see it try to call `_create` here:
```File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arcade/monkey_patch_pyglet.py", line 81, in _create```

Comment: I am not sure it is Anaconda issue. Look at the packages dependencies in the PC to which the code is running. Get the Python version, library used. With Anaconda(conda) you can create an environment with the same requirements and then run the code in that environment.